# Wedge sum of an infinite number of Hausdorff spaces is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to do the exercise 3.55 in the book "Introduction to topological manifolds" by John M. Lee:

> Show that every wedge sum of Hausdorff spaces is Hausdorff.

I have proven this for a finite number of spaces, but I do not know how to prove it when there are infinitely many spaces. My proof in the finite case uses of a finite intersection of open subsets which is open, but I cannot extend this proof to infinite case since an infinite intersection of open subsets is not necessarily open.

Do you have some hints to prove the infinite case?

Comment: @ronno I did this for the finite case and when the two points are contained in at most two of the summands my proof still works for the infinite case, however when one of the points is the wedge point I do not know how to proceed. Can you elaborate a bit this case?

Comment: The easy way is to realize that the wedge sum $\bigvee X_i$ can be defined as a certain subspace of the infinite product $\prod X_i$, more precisely union of (images of) all embeddings $X_j\to \prod X_i$ with fixed other coordinates (base points).

Comment: @freakish do you know a reference where this is explained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(X_i, e_i)$ be the family of Hausdorff pointed spaces. I assume the topology on the wedge sum is the quotient topology induced by the map $q : \bigsqcup X_i \to \bigvee X_i = X$. So to prove that $X$ is Hausdorff, it suffices, for each $x \ne y \in X$, to separate $q^{-1}(x)$ and $q^{-1}(y)$ by disjoint *saturated* open sets in $\bigsqcup X_i$. Note that $q$ is injective away from $\{e_i\}$, in particular any subset of $\bigsqcup X_i \setminus e_i$ is saturated.

Case 1, $x = q(x')$ and $y = q(y')$ for some $x', y' \in X_i \setminus e_i$ for some $i$. Since $X_i$ is Hausdorff, there are disjoint open sets $U$, $V$ in $X_i$ containing $x', y'$ respectively. Since $\{e_i\} \subset X_i$ is closed, assume $U \setminus e_i$ and $V \setminus e_i$ provide a separation.

Case 2, $x = q(x')$ and $y = q(y')$ for some $x' \in X_i \setminus e_i$ and $y' \in X_j \setminus e_j$ with $i \ne j$. Then $X_i \setminus e_i$ and $X_j \setminus e_j$ provide a separation.

Case 3, $x = q(x')$ for some $x' \in X_i \setminus e_i$ and $y = e$ (or the symmetric situtation with $x$ and $y$ swapped). Since $X_i$ is Hausdorff, let $U \ni x'$ and $V \ni e_i$ be disjoint open sets in $X_i$. Then $U$ and $V \cup \bigsqcup_{j \ne i} X_j$ provide a separation.